# Is there an effiecient way to query all files from all users in the Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

The only way I can get this work is to loop through all users and query all the files each user has access to.  This produces a lot of redundant results because if there is a file that is shared organization wide, it's going to be returned for each query per user.  It takes about 10 mins to return all the files within the organization this way.

Here is a rudementary example of my code:

```
gs_directory = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds.with_subject("admin@mydomain.com"))

# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
results = gs_directory.users().list(domain = 'mydomain.com').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])

files = []

if not users:
    print('No users in the domain.')
for user in users:
    print(user["primaryEmail"])
    gs_drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds.with_subject(user["primaryEmail"]))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = gs_drive.files().list(corpora='user',
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])

    while results.get('nextPageToken', None):
        results = gs_drive.files().list(corpora='user', pageToken=results['nextPageToken'],
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

        items += results.get('files', [])

    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: What is the end result of the operation? Searching for each user will return the same file if it is shared with the user, therefore stored in their drive. You can set an array with the id of each file retrieved and make the function check if the file is already in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kessy.  Though it's not shown in my example, that's essentially what I've done in my project. I was just hoping there was a more efficient way to get those unique results with the API.

Comment: Hi have you managed to do it in a more efficient way? If not, can you share more details of how are you doing it and provide more details on how to reproduce what you are doing, so I can try it exactly as you are doing it?